# Gridpane of Squares in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm newer to JavaFX and I'm attempting to make a checkerboard. I first want to start out by making a gridpane of squares that fill with random colors based on 
an array. I'm not sure why, but the squares aren't filling the rest of the grid. I'd also like to use constraints to set the grid height and width.

```
int rowNum = 10;
int colNum = 10;
int gridHeight = 10;
int gridWidth = 10;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    //grid.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(gridWidth));
    //grid.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(gridHeight));

    Random rand = new Random();
    Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED};

    int n = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    for(int row = 0; row < rowNum; row++){
           for(int col = 0; col < colNum; col++){
               Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
               rec.setWidth(2);
               rec.setHeight(2);
               rec.setFill(colors[n]);
               GridPane.setRowIndex(rec, row);
               GridPane.setColumnIndex(rec, col);
               grid.getChildren().addAll(rec);
           }
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 350, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Grid");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Only one square appears on the top left.
Why is this the case?

Comment: You're using the same color for all the rectangles. So you have 100 2x2 rectangles, but they just look like a single 20x20 rectangle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the random number generation step inside the two loops so that you're not using the same color that has been set once before entering the loop. Also, you don't need the plus 1 on that random number generator. The allowed indices are 0-3. When you ask for the nextInt() and input a 4, that's exclusive which means 4 will never be picked (which is what you need for the Color array).

Your code should look like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rowNum; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < colNum; col++) {
        int n = rand.nextInt(4);
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
        rec.setWidth(2);
        rec.setHeight(2);
        rec.setFill(colors[n]);
        GridPane.setRowIndex(rec, row);
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(rec, col);
        grid.getChildren().addAll(rec);
    }
}
```